# VSCode Prettier not formatting PHP

Tags: php, html, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

So I've set up vscode with Prettier, but it will not format .php files.
.html files are working fine with Prettier. So when I have a .php with HTML code then it will be formatted differently, because I am using Beautify as last option.

How can I make Prettier automatically format .php files and the html code in .php the same as .html files?

settings.json

```
{
  "sync.autoDownload": true,
  "sync.autoUpload": true,
  "sync.forceDownload": true,
  "sync.forceUpload": true,
  "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
  "sync.gist": "715bf022af486e449cae9313183b9a56",
  "sync.quietSync": true,
  "typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
  "window.zoomLevel": 0,
  "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.js": "vscode-typescript",
  "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.ts": "vscode-typescript",
  "eslint.codeActionsOnSave.mode": "all",
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Atom One Dark",
  "beautify.language": {
    "html": ["php", "blade"]
  },
  // These are all my auto-save configs
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  // turn it off for JS and JSX, we will do this via eslint
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": false
  },
  "[javascriptreact]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": false
  },
  // tell the ESLint plugin to run on save
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll": true
  },
  // Optional BUT IMPORTANT: If you have the prettier extension enabled for other languages like CSS and HTML, turn it off for JS since we are doing it through Eslint already
  "prettier.disableLanguages": ["javascript", "javascriptreact"],
  "php.validate.executablePath": "C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe"
}
```

.eslintrc.json

```
{
  "extends": ["airbnb", "prettier", "prettier/react"],
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2020,
    // Can I remove these now?
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "impliedStrict": true,
      "classes": true
    }
  },
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true,
    "jquery": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "no-debugger": 0,
    "no-alert": 0,
    "no-await-in-loop": 0,
    "no-return-assign": ["error", "except-parens"],
    "no-restricted-syntax": [
      2,
      "ForInStatement",
      "LabeledStatement",
      "WithStatement"
    ],
    "no-unused-vars": [
      1,
      {
        "ignoreSiblings": true,
        "argsIgnorePattern": "res|next|^err"
      }
    ],
    "prefer-const": [
      "error",
      {
        "destructuring": "all"
      }
    ],
    "arrow-body-style": [2, "as-needed"],
    "no-unused-expressions": [
      2,
      {
        "allowTaggedTemplates": true
      }
    ],
    "no-param-reassign": [
      2,
      {
        "props": false
      }
    ],
    "no-console": 0,
    "import/prefer-default-export": 0,
    "import": 0,
    "func-names": 0,
    "space-before-function-paren": 0,
    "comma-dangle": 0,
    "max-len": 0,
    "import/extensions": 0,
    "no-underscore-dangle": 0,
    "consistent-return": 0,
    "react/display-name": 1,
    "react/no-array-index-key": 0,
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": 0,
    "react/prefer-stateless-function": 0,
    "react/forbid-prop-types": 0,
    "react/no-unescaped-entities": 0,
    "jsx-a11y/accessible-emoji": 0,
    "react/require-default-props": 0,
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [
      1,
      {
        "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"]
      }
    ],
    "radix": 0,
    "no-shadow": [
      2,
      {
        "hoist": "all",
        "allow": ["resolve", "reject", "done", "next", "err", "error"]
      }
    ],
    "quotes": [
      2,
      "single",
      {
        "avoidEscape": true,
        "allowTemplateLiterals": true
      }
    ],
    "prettier/prettier": [
      "error",
      {
        "trailingComma": "es5",
        "singleQuote": true,
        "printWidth": 80
      }
    ],
    "jsx-a11y/href-no-hash": "off",
    "jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid": [
      "warn",
      {
        "aspects": ["invalidHref"]
      }
    ],
    "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks": "error",
    "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "warn"
  },
  "plugins": ["html", "prettier", "react-hooks"]
}
```

Comment: I use the Prettier: Format Selection method on isolated portions of mixed HTML/PHP with better success.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Core prettier does not support PHP<sup>[1](https://prettier.io/docs/en/index.html)</sup>, and thus neither does the plugin for VSCode/VSCodium.
Luckily the designers of prettier seems to have thought of this and implemented a plugin system<sup>[2](https://prettier.io/docs/en/plugins.html)</sup>.

According to the [prettier-vscode](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode) repo, all you need to do to use a plugin is to add it and prettier to your `package.json`<sup>[3](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode#plugins)</sup>

So for php support your package.json would need to contain:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@prettier/plugin-php": "0.14.3",
    "prettier": "2.0.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: This propably works if you only have `.php` files without html. Sadly i found out that `.php` files with html cannot be formatted with prettier.

Comment: If I read that bug you found correctly, it will format the PHP but not the HTML. Suppose the solution they'd prefer you use is to separate your PHP from your HTML.

Comment: then its complete garbage....

Answer (score 15):

Prettier for HTML, CSS, and JavaScript files

change your settings.json

```json
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  // add this code 
  "[php]": {
      "editor.defaultFormatter": "bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client"
  }
```

The settings use Intelephense as the formatter for PHP files and use Prettier as the formatter for all other files.

Now I use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to format the files like everybody else.

if you dont know ho to open setting.json
lets see :
I usually just press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> to get to settings and then click the "Open Settings (JSON)" icon that appears in the top right hand corner under the title bar Here's another option... VS Code: How to open settings.json file? [How can I open Visual Studio Code's 'settings.json' file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65908987/how-can-i-open-visual-studio-codes-settings-json-file)

Comment: If it isn't obvious.. install extension `PHP Intelephense` from `Ben Mewburn`. Confirm that it works.

Comment: Should one purchase license of PHP Intelephense? @Naomak

Comment: At the time I tried it, I didn't buy anything. And from the plugin description it looks you still don't need to. However, I didn't test it in my actual VSCode setup.

Answer (score 12):

run this in VSC terminal, if you already have prettier installed

```
npm install prettier @prettier/plugin-php
```

I managed to format php files with html inside

Comment: It does not work

Comment: This works if you remove `--global` and install it locally.

Answer (score 8):

Sadly there is no support for .php files **with HTML**:
https://github.com/prettier/plugin-php/issues/845

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, and solved it disabling all my extensions : it happens that [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode)

> Aura Components for Visual Studio Code

was making my php code colors disapear.
This extension, however, is part of the "official" Salesforce Extension Pack...

> DO NOT INSTALL THIS EXTENSION DIRECTLY. Install the complete Salesforce Extension Pack instead.

If it could help, check your extensions !!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).